# How can I send an asynchronous e-mail from a shared hosting with PHPMailer?

Tags: php, email

I am using a **shared** hosting and need to send mails asynchronously in PHP. AFAIK PHPMailer is synchronous and doing a simple mail sending script will block for the time the mail is being sent.

**Q**: Is there a way to send mails asynchronously from a shared hosting? I cannot use stuff like [Gearman](http://gearman.org) because it'd require an additional process.

(Notes: If I could choose the server architecture and language, I'd choose a VPS and Python or Java and would not be asking this question. However I have the mentioned constraints of Shared and PHP).

Comment: Ship the process off to a 3rd party, like [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/)?

Comment: Add the mails to a queue and use a cron-job to process the queue periodically.

Comment: That would involve doing a request. How can I do an asynchronous request? AFAIK the url fopen wrappers are synchronous and I don't know how to do async with curl

Comment: @jeroen how do I mount the queue? I'm using a shared hosting.

Comment: Sorry, did not read the "cronjob" part. I'll check whether the hosting service supports cronjobs.

Comment: Passing email message to LOCAL mail server should be pretty fast unless you do bulk mailing.